# Should the CustomEventArgs method implement another Interface?

Tags: unit-testing

Hi I am using test driven development and seem to be in an area I am not familiar. Could you Please check and let me know what changes I should make in my code to make it "unit testable" ?

Code to be tested:

```
public void PurchaseItemList()
{
     //call methods to checkavailablility
     If(!productAvailable)
     {
         purchaseItemEventArgs.IsSuccessfull = false;
     }
     else
     {  
         purchaseItemEventArgs.IsSuccessfull = true;
         // code to update model.
         purchaseItemEventArgs.ItemsPurchased = GetItemsPurchased()
     }
}
```

Now the issue I face is that I cannot mock the purchaseItemEventArgs class as it does not implement any interface. I am using moq for testing. Any advise on the code changes to make it unit testable would be very helpfull.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `GetItemsPurchased()` is a method of your class, you could make it `protected virtual`. So you could then define a test class like this:

```
class TestableMyClass : MyClass{
  private Items _items;

  public TestableMyClass(Items items) : base() {
    _items = items;
  }

  protected Items GetItemsPurchased(){
    return _items;
  }
}
```

And then, in your tests, replace `new MyClass` by `new TestableMyClass(myItems)`.

This way, your actual `GetItemsPurchased()` won't be called in your tests, and you can inject the items you want.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the inputs , but my aim is to test the PurchaseItemList() method and not the GetItemsPurchased() method.

Comment: I actually got through the issue by declaring an interface IpurchaseItemEventArgs and inheriting the purchaseItemEventArgs from this and then mocking the IpurchaseItemEventArgs interface. Is this the right way to test ??

Comment: If your goal is to test `PurchaseItemList` but not `GetItemsPurchased`, my solution works: just call `PurchaseItemList` on the `TestableMyClass`: it will test your actual code, but it will mock the `GetIramsPurchased` you don't want to test